# Deploy app built with appveyor from bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, appveyor

I have an electron app that I build with Appveyor, the build is successful, but I don't know where to get the app built. Appveyor is linked to my repo on bitbucket.

I did not configure much, although I tried without success. I am using electron-vue and the appveyor.yml included in the boilerplate, the explanations tell that the app should be found on the github repo (https://simulatedgreg.gitbooks.io/electron-vue/content/en/using-electron-builder.html) I am using bitbucket, got the webhook working and the it builds successfully but then I cannot find any artifact and I don't know how to configure them.

I tried creating an artifact with the path to the .exe and deploy on s3 but that doesn't seem to work either. It seems like I am missing something here

Comment: Can you please clarify how you created an artifact? Did you follow https://www.appveyor.com/docs/packaging-artifacts/? Can you download and artifact from the `artifacts` tab of successful build?

Comment: added some details

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured that out. It turns out the appveyor.yml needs an artifact definition for my output. As I didn't really know what electron-builder was going to generate for Window I first declared the whole build folder as an artifact

```
artifact:
  - path: build
```

Once the build is complete I downloaded the artifact, build.zip and looked at where the exe was to refine my definition

```
artifact:
  - path: 'build/squirrel-windows/*.exe'
```

And it worked, I can now configure it to deploy on my website and make it available for download